# Why is django context a string when returned to template?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, python-3.x

I'm sending data (id of the selected option from a drop-down) back to my views using some ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {'customer_select': selected_data },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)              
        }
    });
```

I handle it in my class-based view in get_context_data():

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ...
    if 'customer_select' in self.request.GET:
        customer_id = self.request.GET['customer_select']
        context['new_customer_id'] = customer_id
    return context
```

The `success` function in the ajax runs `console.log(data)`. The output is super weird - it's basically the html of my page source. I don't understand how to parse `context` within `success`. I want to be able to access `new_customer_id` in `success`. When I do `console.log(typeof data)` it returned `string`. Why is data (and by extension context) a string?

Comment: You probably need to return a json response

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#jsonresponsemixin-example